# microsoft graph rest api: update application fails with error badrequest - Error: Property value is required but is empty or missing

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, beta

I'm trying to use microsoft graph api to manage my aad applications (in B2C tenant), i can create and get applications, but fail to update any existing one.

request url: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications/{appId}

request body:

```
{
 "displayName":"abcd",
 "api":{
    "requestedAccessTokenVersion":2,
    "oauth2PermissionScopes":   [{
        "adminConsentDescription":"write",
        "adminConsentDisplayName":"write",
        "userConsentDescription":"write",
        "userConsentDisplayName":"write",
        "type":"User",
        "value":"write",
        "isEnabled":true
    }]
  }
}
```

Error:

```
 "code": "ValueRequired",
 "message": "Property  value is required but is empty or missing.",
```

I checked the api schema from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/apiapplication?view=graph-rest-beta), it should work. No clue which property i'm missing. please help.

Comment: Were you able to work it out ?

Answer (score 1):

This error is returned when you're missing the id parameter:

```js
{
  "api": {
        "oauth2PermissionScopes": [{
            "adminConsentDescription": "A description.",
            "adminConsentDisplayName": "A display name.",
            "id": "d6a95d36-1234-1234-1234-3ce8a7b84fa2",
            "isEnabled": true,
            "type": "Admin",
            "value": "user_impersonation"
            }]
    }
}
```

The way I worked this out was to create an entry via the Portal then use AZ CLI to retrieve the JSON for what you want to create:

```
az ad app show --id $appObjectId --query api
```

Create a file with the JSON then in Powershell you can:

```
az rest --method PATCH --uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/$appObjectId" --headers "Content-Type=application/json" --body @manifest.json
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely due to your oauth2PermissionsScopes section.  That does not look right.  Try removing that section and see it it works.  It would help to get a complete error message including request id and time stamp

Comment: Thanks for your response. request is succeeded if removing the oauth2PermissionsScopes, while my purpose is to add api scopes using this oauth2PermissionsScopes. here's the complete error:  

Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error": {
    "code": "ValueRequired",
    "message": "Property  value is required but is empty or missing.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "3c7ce256-3152-4f55-8a0c-a2c089957684",
      "date": "2019-11-27T01:39:23"
    }
  }
}